# how to open all record inserted from data loader

Tags: lookup, data-migration

i confuse with salesforce, how can i use records that insert from data loader without open the record manually.

Example : i create custom object 'Book' just contain Name standard field,
 then i create another custom object 'Student' with lookup field into 'Book'.

And then, i use data loader, insert records of Book : 'Book1', 'Book2', 'Book3'.

Now i create 1 student record, and want use Book1 or Book2 , how can i choose Book1 or the other without open the record ? because my recent view is still blank.

Thanks.

Comment: You can export already inserted records using Data Loader Export option.

Comment: do you need that on Student insert page using lookup?

Comment: cant sir Devendra |||
what i want to achieve is, I can use records, that i inserted from data loader into lookup field in Student (recent view still blank cause i'm not open the record ''Book1", "Book2", "Book3") @Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your statement "how can i choose Book1 or the other without open the record" to mean that you want to load a new Student record that refers to a specific Book record which you previously loaded.

During load Salesforce created an id for each Book. This id is hidden in the UI.

1. Export all Book records using the data loader. The exported CSV will have the ids for each Book.
2. Edit the Student CSV file and add the ids to the lookup field of each Student.
3. Run the data loader on the Student CSV file and it will create the lookup relationship between the Student and corresponding Book.